# Python, range(), double loops,

Tags: python, range

Codes and result are shown below.

I'm curious about the prints beginning wiht 1 instead of 0 as start.
Where does the program get 1 from?

Can someone please help me here? Thanks!

```
for i in range(5) :
    for j in range(i) :
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()
```

1 
2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4

The same result with codes below:

```
for i in range(5) :
    for j in range(0, i) :
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()
```

By altering (0, i) to (1, i), it's also logically omitted 1, but how does it come to a single 2 as the result shown below?

```
for i in range(5) :
    for j in range(1, i) :
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()
```

2 
3 3 
4 4 4

Comment: How many times did you expect `0` to be printed?

Comment: When `i` is 0, `range(i)` is empty.

Comment: When `i` is 0, `for j in range(i)` does nothing...

Comment: Thanks buddys for your kindness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `for j in range(0):` loops 0 times, so it never prints `i` when its 0. If you look closely at your output, you'll see that the first line is actually blank.

Comment: Thanks Snake! I did doubt why there was much space, but did not come across to 0 as an empty line! Shame on me! BTW, I still do not quite catch what caused the missing of 1 when altered to for i in range(5) : for j in range(1, i) : Is it because range(1, 0) being ignored by no error feeding back? Could you still help? Thanks!

Comment: Range doesn't include the last number. ```range(1) = range(0, 1) = 0```` It's the same reason why you're not outputting any 5's

Comment: Thanks Snake! I've got the following quotations: Note: the set generated by the range() has to be sorted in ascending order. There's no way to force the range() to create a set in a different form when the range() function accepts exactly two arguments. This means that the range()'s second argument must be greater than the first. Hence range(0,0) and range(1,1), both in form (i,i), won't give the print-out. Still I do not understand why we've got a 2 in the first line upon changing (0, i ) to (1, i)? Thanks again!